# Get-AzureLocation - Resource Manager Alternative

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

There is a Azure ASM command Get-AzureLocation that gets the available data centre locations for the current Azure subscription. However, there doesn't appear to be an Azure RM alternative - can anyone provide an Azure Resource Manager alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Get-AzureRMLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermlocation?view=azurermps-4.1.0)

[See related discussion here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1299) as looks like this was removed and re-added at some point.